# Mysql select where date between 'yy/dd/MM' and 'yy/dd/MM'

Tags: mysql, simpledateformat

I am stuck in a situation where I am reading data from CSV file through 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' and storing it in Mysql table.

**The date column in my table is of type string.**

The below query is not working if my Date format is **'yy/dd/MM'**, it only returns 2 records

```
select column1, column2 from myTable where date between '16/08/15' and '16/08/20';
```

and if I ran this:

```
select column1, column2 from myTable where date > '16/08/15';
```

It return all records.

Is there a way to ran the first query so I can specify start  and end date ?

Comment: try using (and) `where date >= '16/08/15' and date <= '16/08/20';` ?

Comment: change type of date column from string to date

Answer (score 0):

Turn your dates into 'yyyy-mm-dd' format before using them inside queries, and it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the year as yy try to pass it as yyyy in the date string since my sql stores dates in that format.Since every year is a four digit one, giving a two digit year in the where clause in order to pull out all records greater than that year will actually pull out all the records.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say your date column is of type "String" and not DATE so in your query mysql is not operating the between function on dates, instead it's operating it on strings. You probably need to cast you string dates to actual dates before applying the between function. see e.g. [str_to_date function.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)